# How to determine the datatype of a field in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I wanted to determine the datatype of a field in my JSON document in MongoDB. Is it possible to do so? Example if I have

```
{
    "created_at": "Fri Aug 04 05:42:03 +0000 2017",
    "id": 893346273255866400,
    "id_str": "893346273255866368"
}
```

I wanted to know what type of values "created_at" accepts so I can formulate a query in my MongoDB

Comment: You can use the typeof operater to return the type of value in MongoDB. For more information see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#check-types-in-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the typeof operater to return the type of value in MongoDB and you can also query by a specific type by using $type operator in query. 
e.g.

```
db.inventory.find( { price: { $type: "decimal" } } )
```

For more information see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#check-types-in-shell